# Caldera Forms Calculo de Precio

Tags: php, wordpress, formularios

estoy realizando un formulario de calculo de precios sencillo con el plugin Caldera Form. El problema surge cuando seleccion una casilla del desplegable y no me muestra ningún precio (cuando deberia mostrarlo)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le ha pasado esto a alguien?
Adjunto imagenes de como lo tengo configurado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe donde puede estar el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente en tu Tema de Wordpress utilizas una versión de Jquery no compatible con el Plugin de Caldera Forms, intenta canviarla por esta versión:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```